# Seeding users with membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to seed some users with the `SimpleMembershipProvider`. I have added a few columns in the UserProfile table, like a mobile number. When i try to add a user with a mobile number, the compiler tells me:

```
The name 'Mobile' does not exist in the current context
```

This is the class:

```
namespace _DataContext.Migrations {
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebMatrix.WebData;
    using System.Web.Security;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<_DataContext.DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(_DataContext.DataContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //

        SeedMembership();
    }

    private void SeedMembership()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);


        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
            var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider;

            if (!roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
                roles.CreateRole("Administrator");

            if (membership.GetUser("Username", false) == null)
                membership.CreateUserAndAccount("Username", "Pass", false, 
                    new Dictionary<string, object> 
                    { 
                        { Mobile = "+311122334455" }, 
                    });

            /*if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("test"))
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                    "Username",
                    "password",
                    new { 
                            Mobile = "+311122334455", 
                            FirstName = "test", 
                            LastName = "test",
                            LoginCount = 0,
                            IsActive = true,
                        });
              */
    }
  }
}
```

If I use the `WebSecurity` everything goes fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the way you are creating your `Dictionary`, you can't do:

```
membership.CreateUserAndAccount("Username", "Pass", false,
    new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { Mobile = "+311122334455" }, // Mobile won't compile here
    });
```

so instead use:

```
membership.CreateUserAndAccount("Username", "Pass", false,
    new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { "Mobile", "+311122334455" }, // Mobile should be the string in the string, object pair
    });
```

For what it's worth, `WebSecurity` does exactly the same as you are doing, but stops you having to specify the exact provider in your code.

Comment: Hi, make sense, think i have tried that option too, not sure though. But what do you mean with websecurity stops me from specifying the exact provider?

Comment: @Yustme. It just abstracts you away from the concrete provider implementation. Its code also takes `Membership.Provider`, but casts it to the common base class for all providers instead of `SimpleMembershipProvider` (so is potentially better for IoC and/or DI). Unless you are super worried about performance, I would use WebSecurity.